# PowerShell: how to read a log-file as of a specific number within the lines?

Tags: file, powershell

I want to read a log file in each line is a sequence number. Now I'd like to get all lines that have seq.no. greater or equal than $low = 111 and less or eqal than $high = 123 - can I do that with a Where-Object:

```
 $LogEntries = Get-Content -Path $LogFile | Where-Object {
        $f = $_ -maltch 'EntryNo=(\d+)\D'
        if ($f) {
           [decimal]n = mathches[1]
           if ( n -ge $low -and n -le $high ) {
             # how to continue?
           }
         }
 }
```

If this is possible how can I complete the brackets?

Thanks in advance,
gooly

Loegfile Entrioes:

```
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=109;Tag=..
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=110;Tag=..
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=111;Tag=..
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=112;Tag=..
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=113;Tag=..
 PowerShell;Test.ps1;....;SeqNo=114;Tag=..
```

...

Comment: Can you post a line of your Logfile? Just an Idea: Maybe you can use the -split parameter to extract the sequence number

Comment: You need to use `ForEach-Object` to loop over the file contents. When you have a match, I'd suggest storing the matched line in an array or writing it to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the pipeline how it's supposed to be used:

1. Get the file contents

   ```
   Get-Content logfile |
   ```
2. Filter for sequence number

   ```
   where {
     if ($_ -match 'SeqNo=\d+') {
       $seq = +$Matches[1]     # The + in front coerces the match to a number
       $seq -ge $low -and $seq -le $high
     } else { $false }
   }
   ```

For added elegance, the comparison for high and low can also be done as follows:

```
where { $low..$high -eq $seq }
```

(Might be a little slower, depending on how large the gap between `$low` and `$high` is.)